# Performing OR in regex capture groups

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I would like a match if the `value` contains either `digits` or matches the pattern `[lookup('key')]` where `key` can be any string.

Using either pattern on its own works.  For example this works.

```
string value = "[lookup('anykey')]";

if (!Regex.IsMatch(value, "^\\[(lookup)\\(.*\\)\\]$"))
   {
       Console.WriteLine("no match");
   }
```

I couldn't get both to work with a single regex.

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(value, "((\\d+) | (\\[(parameter)\\(.*\\)\\]))"))
   {
       Console.WriteLine("no match");
   }
```

Any idea?

Comment: @ is your friend

Comment: @Sergio yes silly mistake. Go ahead and answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your regex you should remove spaces, try:

[`\d+|\[lookup\('[^']+'\)\]`](https://regex101.com/r/Y7BwnN/1)

Answer (score 0):

First of all whenever I use regular expression in c# or for that matter any string that has characters that require escaping I prefix the string with '@' symbol, which saves me from using double escapes:)...I find it easier

Ok now to the answer, here is what I think you are looking for

---

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //string value = "[lookup('BlahBlah')]";
        string value = "789897";
        Match m = Regex.Match(value, @"((\d+)|(\[lookup\(\'([^\']+)\'\)\]))") ;
        if (m.Success)
        {
            string num = m.Groups[2].Value;
            string key = m.Groups[4].Value;
        } 
    }
```

---

Notice how the string was prefixed with the '@' symbol and I didn't have to use double escapes for symbol \.
Since we are using so many parenthesis, we have 5 groups overall and if you want the number then you take the value of group 1, if you want the key the you take the value of group 4. If the 'num' is an empty string that means no number was supplied etc...
Hope that helps .....